# Why XAML doesn't need to be compiled?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, compilation

If I create a button in XAML I can directly view it in internet explorer, however if I create the same button in C# I need to compile the code first. Why does it work that way? How does the browser know what to display, shouldn't it treat the XAML as pure XML.

For example, if I have a pure XAML file, that has no reference to code behind, I can open it in internet explorer and it displays it, I am wondering why it works this way, without any compilation?

Comment: Well, nobody ever had to compile HTML to get it working in a browser...

Comment: Please give more context... what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: I updated the question, hope this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

This is because very early versions of Silverlight supported XAML files in the raw. It's not considered best practice to deploy applications in this way, but it's probably fine if you just have an animation or vector image you want to render. You can read more in this old article here:

http://www.windows-now.com/blogs/rrelyea/archive/2004/1.aspx